# Moving (comet tail) effect of particle emitter without actual moving

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x, particles

I have a Sprite in my scene and there is a particle emitter inside this sprite. So, when I move the sprite (using MoveTo action), then i can see moving animation for both, sprite and particle emitter. MoveTo animation wasn't affected to old particles (which were emitted before animation was started) and i can see something like a tail, like from a comet. So everything is ok. Now, if i will create move action for sprite and move it by, let say, 100 pixels up and make an action with 100 pixels down for emitter then emitter will move by 100 pixels relatively to sprite, but will stay still relatively to screen and there will be no "comet tail" effect. So, it means that emitted particles aren't belong to sprite, but to something else.

So, my question is: how can I make move "comet tail" effect without actual moving relatively to screen? Or imagine, I have a layer with a sun emitter. And on some point I will decide to move this layer (scroll it) and my sun emitter will also scrolls with the layer, but old emitted particles will make "comet tail" effect because they're not belong to the layer, but to something else. How can move that scene without "comet tail" effect?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so here are the Position Types specified by cocos2d's particle engine:

- FREE
  Living particles are attached to the world and are unaffected by emitter repositioning.
- RELATIVE
  Living particles are attached to the world but will follow the emitter repositioning.
  *Use case: Attach an emitter to an sprite, and you want that the emitter follows the sprite.*
- GROUPED
  Living particles are attached to the emitter and are translated along with it.

If you don't want to have particles move relatively to the world, then you need either RELATIVE or GROUPED.

If you WANT the particles to form a trail, you need FREE.

```
emitter->setPositionType(_posType);
```

If you think that I'm not getting your point, please post some code to illustrate the problem - it's a bit difficult to understand your issue.

Comment: I don't need gravity. I want to specify relative parent to particle system (not just to emitter). How can I move scene with particle emitter and avoid comet tail effect using gravity?

Comment: updated my answer. If I'm still off the subject, please post some code to explain the issue.

Comment: almost there... I have a layer and an emitter as a child of this layer. So, now I want to move the layer up on 100 pixels and move emitter down on 100 pixels, so, it should make an effect like background is moving, but emitter is not. And I want tail effect in this scenario. By default i doesn't show any tail because it looks like living particles are attached to the world coordinates...

Comment: but i need them to be attached to the background layer... gravity won't work because movement of background is chaotic...